# delegate declared in interface/protocol?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols

could you help me understand something with the delegates and protocols :
in this code :

> ```
>           @protocol FirstViewControllerDelegate;  
>             @interface FirstViewController : UIVIewController {
>             …
>             id<FirstViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
>             }
>             @property (assign) id <FirstViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
> ```

- what does mean the first line "@protocol" ? i don't see in my project this delegate file, and the current file (with @interface) seems to be a "simple" interface for my FirstViewController, so i'm a bit confused.
- i've seen how to use the delegate pattern, but i've never seen that we need to "declare" the delegate in the .h, is it something that must be written in the .h file (i'm talking about id < .... > delegate) ?

Thanks for your answer

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
@protocol FirstViewControllerDelegate;
```

in that format is a forward declaration. It tells the compiler that `FirstViewControllerDelegate` is a valid protocol that will be defined later on (sometimes just further down in the same .h file). It is required because without it the compiler will complain when it sees the line

```
id<FirstViewControllerDelegate>
```

as it has not seen its declaration.

The actual protocol may be defined something like

```
@protocol FirstViewControllerDelegate
{
@required
  - (void)myImportantDelegateMethod;
}
```

Comment: ok thanks! and about the id <...> why is it something needed?

Comment: It tells the compiler that although it can be an object of any type `id` it should conform to the protocol in `< ... >`

Comment: oh by the way, could you tell me one last thing : we normally set the delegate property to a specific object, bu if we just declare the delegate as it is here, it will delegate "itself" ? so consequently : the uiviewController? it's easier to understand it i think when it delegates a specific action, but here, i'm not sure of what it does. Thanks for your answer

Comment: The delegate property is declared `id` because we do not know which object will act as a delegate and conform to our protocol. The `< ... >` part of the property declaration tells the compiler to make sure that the object that is assigned to `delegate` implements the protocol. If in our class we define a `@required` method in our protocol our object does not care what type the object is (hence the `id`) that is assigned the `delegate` but only that is follows our protocol (`< ... >`) and implements our required methods.

Comment: ok, if we use a protocol, we must use it with the delegate right? thanks for the explanation ;)